# "nec sit terris ultima Thule" - how should terris be interpreted?

Tags: grammar-identification

Seneca's *Medea*:

> Venient annis saecula seris,
> quibus Oceanus vincula rerum
> laxet, et ingens pateat tellus,
> Tethysque novos detegat orbes
> **nec sit terris ultima Thule**.

I have my doubts with respect to the grammatical function of *terris* (it results in slightly different meaning; in some of those, for example, Thule is not considered to be part of the *terrae*):

- ablative of place ("farthest in lands") - but without preposition it makes me wonder.
- ablative of separation ("farthest from lands". i.e. "from/of all the lands, Thule isn't the farthest") - I would usually, maybe wrongly, expect the genitive in those cases.
- ablative of separation ("farthest from lands". i.e. a very remote place distance-wise from the "lands")
- dative ("farthest for/to the lands")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(For reference, these are lines 375–379.)

I'm not sure it's necessary to link *terris* as closely to *ultima* as you're doing. I myself construe it as a dative: 'nor Thule be for the known world [the] remotest [spot].' Specifically, I think I'd take it as a dative of possession: 'nor the known world have Thule as [its] most remote [spot].'

Still, a looser English translation would make it sound as though the Latin were using a local ablative: 'nor Thule be the remotest spot on earth.'